# How to interlace an iterator with itself from the end?

Tags: rust, iterator, rust-itertools

I have an iterator in the form `0..=63`, i.e.
`0 1 2 3 4 ... 59 60 61 62 63`.
Its `.count()` is 64.

How would I get the following iterator:
`0 63 1 62 2 61 3 60 4 59 ...`
(of course independent of the items present in the iterator), preferably without cloning?
The `.count()` should stay the same, as only the order of items should change.

I've looked in the standard library and couldn't find it, same in the `itertools` crate.

Comment: You can do crimes with iterator adapters, but I'll probably write a custom iterator. It's not that hard.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Why should I want to write a custom iterator? I have another iterator and I want to perform this operation.

Comment: I meant a custom iterator adapter.

Comment: But my craziness requires me to do [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7666144634c4d22f496bf82f5c84577d).

Comment: Or better [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0d38741006ca10ec04ecaeaa8b4b0ecf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution works for all iterators that implement `DoubleEndedIterator`:

Note that this solution is guaranteed to return all items, regardless of whether the iterator contains an even or odd number of them.

```rust
fn selfinterlace<Iter>(mut iter: Iter) -> impl Iterator<Item = Iter::Item>
where
    Iter: DoubleEndedIterator,
{
    let mut from_front = false;

    std::iter::from_fn(move || {
        from_front = !from_front;
        if from_front {
            iter.next()
        } else {
            iter.next_back()
        }
    })
}

fn main() {
    let range = (0..=8).into_iter();
    let iter = selfinterlace(range);
    println!("{:?}", iter.collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

```
[0, 8, 1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4]
```

The idea is that you store whether the next item should be from the front or the back, and then flip that in every iteration.

`from_fn` can take `FnMut`, meaning, it can take closures that store internal state. The internal state in this closure consists of the variables `iter` and `from_front`, which get moved into the closure through the `move ||` keyword.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way using only the standard library. It requires a `DoubleEndedIterator` and will skip the last item for odd sized iterators:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut range = (0..=63).into_iter();
    let iter = std::iter::from_fn(|| Some([range.next()?, range.next_back()?])).flatten();
    dbg!(iter.collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

Output:

```
[src/main.rs:4] iter.collect::<Vec<_>>() = [
    0,
    63,
    1,
    62,
    2,
    61,
    3,
...

    30,
    33,
    31,
    32,
]
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f49d56d76f248219e8c20727de2d815c)

---

@Finomnis [has posted a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72866663) in case your input has an odd number of items.

Comment: I think the fact that it skips an element is dangerous and might lead to very subtle bugs. Especially if people just copy-paste from this answer.

Here is a version of your solution that doesn't skip the last element for odd ranges:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ec03e9e3b788daa5f5b1121a546b1c76

Maybe you could incorporate that into the answer somehow.

Comment: I added my own answer, I'll delete it if you incorporate it in yours.

Comment: @Finomnis that's a much better solution than mine for the generic case. You should keep it - I'll edit my answer to include a link to it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`itertools::interleave`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/fn.interleave.html) to interleave forward and reverse iterators.

- `RangeInclusive<i32>` doesn't implement `ExactSizedIterator` so there's no `.len()` function. We have to calculate it ourselves.
- If the range has an odd length the extra item will show up in the forward half thanks to `(len + 1)`.

```
let range = 0..=63;
let len = range.end() - range.start() + 1;
let iter = itertools::interleave(
    range.clone().take((len + 1) / 2),
    range.clone().rev().take(len / 2),
);
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=61f70bf1c4063f7499c433de4d6dd195)</sup>